# Unknown column 'aliasiteratedays.symbol' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to solve this I tried different kinds of solutions to no avail i tried removing alias aliasiteratedays then just use t.aliasiteratedays.symbol ON WHERE clause. Here's my code:

```
"INSERT INTO currentweekvalue (symbol,value)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT currentweekvalue.symbol as csymbol, (currentweekvalue.value + aliasiteratedays.value) as totval
FROM currentweekvalue  
LEFT JOIN $dayiterated as aliasiteratedays
ON currentweekvalue.symbol = aliasiteratedays.symbol) t
WHERE t.csymbol = concat('t.',aliasiteratedays.symbol)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(t.totval)";
```

u link my question to my question then state a possible duplicate. Kindly check again. Thanks

Comment: You are referring to column in inner select in where for outer select

Comment: I can't understand what should I do?

Comment: aliasiteratedays.symbol  is form a table declare in the inner subselect  .. you can't use in where of the  external select

Comment: @scaisEdge thank you for explaining you don't know how happy I am. Is there a workaround for this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create an alias in SELECT statement in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128671/cant-create-an-alias-in-select-statement-in-mysql)